# Video player for mobile (android & iphone) that support VAST

Tags: html, html5-video

I am looking for a Video player that can run on both iPhone/iPad and Android phones.

The main issue is the ability to handle VAST (video advertisement tags)

Any suggestion are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching the only solution I have found is a player from Kaltura.

(They got an open source player too)

[link](https://github.com/kaltura/player-sdk-native-android)

Comment: Can i integrate that to my Android app ?